# How to avoid redundant logins when instantiating inter-dependent objects?

Tags: python, class, python-requests

I have two classes: `LogSess` (for login) and `DataReq` (for fetching a json).

The problem I face is that the instantiation of `DataReq` depends on the one of `LogSss`. So whenever I create `DataReq` objects, I keep logged in again and again. The desired behaviour is to trigger the login only if it's the first time we instantiate a `LogSess` object or if the cookies have expired or if the website returns a response that contains the text "You must login".

Do you guys know how to achieve this ? Is this even possible ? I'm open to any suggestion.

PS : I have three more similar classes like `DataReq` that also depends on `LogSess`.

```
import requests
 
URL_LOGIN = "https://www/login..."
URL_TDATA = "https://www/services-..."

class LogSess:
    def __init__(self, username="foo", password="bar"):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    @property
    def session(self):
        with requests.Session() as session:
            session.post(URL_LOGIN, data={"login": self.username, "password": self.password})
            return session

class DataReq:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = None

    @property
    def data(self):
        response = LogSess().session.post(URL_TDATA, data={"name": self.name})

        try:
            return response.json()
        except JSONDecodeError:
            print("Session expired! Need to re-login.")
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid redundant logins when instantiating inter-dependent objects, you might consider a [singleton pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/python/example#example-1) for `LogSess` (a thread-safe singleton). That unique instance manages the session and login state. It should only log in if it is not already logged in or if the session has expired.

Add a method in `LogSess` to validate if the current session is active. That can be based on the cookies' expiry or a test request to the server.

Pass the `LogSess` instance to `DataReq` instead of creating a new one inside `DataReq`. That way, `DataReq` uses the existing session managed by `LogSess`.

And modify `DataReq` to handle scenarios where the session has expired, triggering a re-login through `LogSess`.

```py
import requests
from threading import Lock

URL_LOGIN = "https://www/login..."
URL_TDATA = "https://www/services-..."

class SingletonMeta(type):
    """
    Thread-safe implementation of Singleton.
    """
    _instances = {}
    _lock: Lock = Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        with cls._lock:
            if cls not in cls._instances:
                instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
                cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]

class LogSess(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self, username="foo", password="bar"):
        self._session = None
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def login(self):
        if not self._session:
            self._session = requests.Session()
            self._session.post(URL_LOGIN, data={"login": self.username, "password": self.password})

    @property
    def session(self):
        self.login()
        return self._session

    # Add any other necessary methods here

class DataReq:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.log_sess = LogSess()
        self.name = name
        self._data = None

    @property
    def data(self):
        try:
            response = self.log_sess.session.post(URL_TDATA, data={"name": self.name})
            self._data = response.json()
        except JSONDecodeError:
            print("Session expired! Need to re-login.")
            self.log_sess.login()
            response = self.log_sess.session.post(URL_TDATA, data={"name": self.name})
            self._data = response.json()
        return self._data

# Usage
data_req = DataReq("example_name")
print(data_req.data)
```

The `login` method is called within the `session` property to make sure the session is established before any data requests are made.
`DataReq` creates an instance of `LogSess` using the singleton pattern, making sure all `DataReq` instances share the same `LogSess` instance.

Comment: I really don't see why a singleton should be used. It's not outside the realm of my imagination that one might want to have two sessions at the same time and be performing requests with both "at the same time" (either interleaved, or on different threads).

Comment: @starball I agree and have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options.

1. You could make `DataReq.data` take a `Session` or a `LogSess` as an argument.
2. If you're married to the `LogSess` class, I'd make its `session` getter at least cache the session it creates, and try to return the cached one the next time it's called, but create and cache a new one if the previous one can't be used, or a new one is needed (Ex. session expired after a known timeout). Then I'd suggest to add a function to `LogSess` like `LogSess.request` that takes a function that takes a `Session` and performs an action that returns a response. You could make `LogSess.request` handle errors like expiration by re-creating the `Session`, and handle login-needed errors by requesting different login details from the user if needed (but why? you already have a `username` and `password`). Then change `DataReq.data` to use the `LogSess` it takes as an argument, and use it to call its `request` function, passing a lambda or something that, then takes the returned response and returns the JSON-ified version. How you do error handling is up to you.
3. Or you could invert that and make `LogSess` have a function that performs requests, and takes an object that provides a getter for how to perform the request, and one for what transformation to perform on the response for successful for return, and one for what to do upon errors. Then there would be no `LogSess.session` getter.

Answer (score -1):

Issue of having multiple classes like `DataReq` depending on `LogSess` for a session, in order to solve it you can implement shared session management approach, because it will ensure that a login occurs only when necessary (for example, when cookie expire, when prompted by a "You must login", or even during the first instantiation of `LogSess`).
To solve this, I'd approach it in a way where I would make use of Singleton Pattern for `LogSess` and Session validation and refresh (similar to what @VonC did, but he didn't include second part).

Why?

- By implementing singleton pattern for `LogSess`, you're ensuring that only one instance of `LogSess` is created and that exactly same instance is reused for all future requests, that way login process will only happen once, or when needed based on the criteria OP mentioned. Second thing is when you do session validation and refresh, which is going to include methods in `LogSess` in order to validate if session is still active and to refresh the login if necessary, and that one would be based on cookie expiration or specific response content indicating a required login.

```
    import requests
    from json import JSONDecodeError
    
    URL_LOGIN = "https://www/login..."
    URL_TDATA = "https://www/services-..."
    
    class LogSess:
        _instance = None
    
        def __new__(cls, username="foo", password="bar"):
            if cls._instance is None:
                cls._instance = super(LogSess, cls).__new__(cls)
                cls._instance.session = requests.Session()
                cls._instance.username = username
                cls._instance.password = password
                cls._instance.login()
            return cls._instance
    
        def login(self):
            self.session.post(URL_LOGIN, data={"login": self.username, "password": self.password})
    
        def refresh_session(self):
            # Check for cookie expiration or specific response content here
            # If required, call self.login()
    
    class DataReq:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self._data = None
    
        @property
        def data(self):
            if self._data is None:
                log_sess = LogSess()
                response = log_sess.session.post(URL_TDATA, data={"name": self.name})
    
                try:
                    self._data = response.json()
                except JSONDecodeError:
                    print("Session expired! Need to re-login.")
                    log_sess.refresh_session()
                    self._data = log_sess.session.post(URL_TDATA, data={"name": self.name}).json()
            return self._data
    
    # Usage
    data_request = DataReq("example")
    print(data_request.data)
```

In this implementation `LogSess` is a Singleton, the login method is called during the first instantiation and `refresh_session` can be used to check and refresh the session itself as needed, also, the `DataReq` class uses the instance of `LogSess` to get session and handle data fetching, including session refresh if necessary.

Also, one more reason to use Singleton pattern is that it provides a global point of access to it, which is particulary useful in managin resources like session handling (you might want to avoid creating multiple instances of class that manages a shared resource).

For those who're in concern, of course it's important to mention that Singleton can be very useful for certain use cases like session management, they could be considered as an anti-pattern due to potentional issues like facing difficulties in testing and the risk of misuse as global variables, so you have to use them judiciously and understand the implications of their use in your application.

Comment: did you not see my comment under VonC's answer?

Comment: I did see it, it's  just that I don't see your ideas necessary better than VonC's and mine suggestions even though he agreed with you, and I could state at least 6 valid points against why singleton should be used, including thread safety and sync, design pattern recognition, resource management (that prevents replication of resource-intensive objects, thereby optimizing memory and resourse usage), consistency and control which would offer centralized point of control and consistency in session handling where you have unified session context being necessary, which can be crucial. @starball